# Pushing to Heroku a Java worker that contains local dependencies via Maven

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am following [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes-java-quartz-rabbitmq). Also, on my **local** machine I have two Maven projects; let's call them:

1. `MyAppDAO` (contains all database related code),
2. `MyAppWorker` (performs the background tasks on the database).

The relationship between the two is that `MyAppWorker` includes `MyAppDAO` as a Maven dependency so that it can work with the database; in the `pom.xml` of `MyAppWorker` I have

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.someone.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyAppDAO</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I was able to make it work locally, yet whenever I try to push `MyAppWorker` to Heroku, I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MyAppWorker: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.someone.myapp:MyAppWorker:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.someone:MyAppDAO:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

My best guess is that I have to tell Maven **not** to search `MyAppDAO` at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 but to look at the `<project_folder>/target/dependency`, yet I did not find any helpful information on how to resolve the issue assuming my guess is correct in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Following [these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) solved my problem.